# Merge 2 arrays to single array if any two keys of both array matches

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:
1. first array:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => int 1
      'section_id' => int 2
      'class_id' => int 25
      'student_id' => int 1
      'unixdate' => int 1322553600
      'date' => string '2011-11-29' (length=10)
      'attendance' => string 'present' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => int 2
      'section_id' => int 2
      'class_id' => int 25
      'student_id' => int 2
      'unixdate' => int 1322553600
      'date' => string '2011-11-29' (length=10)
      'attendance' => string 'absent' (length=6)
```

2. second array:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'section_id' => int 2
      'class_id' => int 25
      'student_id' => int 1
      'unixdate' => int 1322553600
      'date' => string '2011-11-29' (length=10)
      'attendance' => string 'absent' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array
      'section_id' => int 2
      'class_id' => int 25
      'student_id' => int 3
      'unixdate' => int 1322553600
      'date' => string '2011-11-29' (length=10)
      'attendance' => string 'absent' (length=6)
```

ON these array if values of two keys 'student_id' and 'unixdate' matches I want new array with the id from array one and other from array 2.

OR
replace the 'attendance' value to first array if 'student_id' and 'unixdate' of both array are same.

**EDIT**
my result should be like this:

```
array
      0 => 
        array
          'id'  => int 1
          'section_id' => int 2
          'class_id' => int 25
          'student_id' => int 1
          'unixdate' => int 1322553600
          'date' => string '2011-11-29' (length=10)
          'attendance' => string 'absent' (length=7)
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try with 2 foreach?

```
$result = array();
foreach($array1 as $data1)
{
  foreach($array2 as $data2)
  {
    if($data1['student_id'] == $data2['student_id'] and
       $data1['unixdate'] == $data2['unixdate'])
    {
        $tmp = array("id" => $data1['id']);
        $tmp = array_merge($tmp, $data2);

        $result[] = $tmp;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @kamal, I edited my answer. Basically it seems that you want the data from the first array if there's a match between array1 and array2, isn't it?

Comment: I want the data from the second array and id from the first array. because second array comes from form and is 2 be updated in database.

Comment: @kamal sorry, it seemed that you wanted the first array. I edited my answer with the result you want.